# this project won't read ints as binary and output them as binary to a new file

Tags: c++, iostream

I have 6 ints 
25
5
30
6
20
36
in a txt file. The program opens the txt file ok. In my "cout for loop" in main, the program outputs what appears to be binary representations of the ints. But, the output file contains  the extract same ints, not binary data. I got this sample from my text book. How can I fix it to read in ints and write out binary ints?

```
#include "lib.h"
//========================================================================================
//========================================================================================

 void open_infile(ifstream& ifs)
{
    string infile;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file:";
    cin >> infile;

   ifs.open(infile.c_str(), ios_base::binary);
    if (!ifs) error("can't open out file");
}

//========================================================================================
//========================================================================================

 void open_outfile(ofstream& ost)
{
    string outfile;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file:";
    cin >> outfile;

    ost.open(outfile.c_str(), ios_base::binary);
    if (!ost) error("can't open out file");
}

//========================================================================================
//========================================================================================

 void get_fileContent(ifstream& ifs, vector<int>& v)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(ifs.read(as_bytes(i),sizeof(int)))
        v.push_back(i);
}
 //========================================================================================
//========================================================================================

 void write_fileContent(ofstream& ost, vector<int>& v)
{
    for(int i  =0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        {   
        ost.write(as_bytes(v[i]),sizeof(int));
        }

}
//========================================================================================
//========================================================================================

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs;
    ofstream ost;
    vector<int> v;

    open_infile(ifs);

    get_fileContent(ifs, v);


    //just checking to make sure data is being copied to int vector correctly
    for(int i  =0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        {   
        cout<< endl << v[i]<< endl;
        }

    open_outfile(ost);

    write_fileContent(ost, v);

    keep_window_open();

}
//========================================================================================
//========================================================================================
```

The output from the for loop in main is:
168637746
856296757
906628400
808585741
909314573

Comment: What do you think a binary file is? One that when you open it in a text editor will show you 0s and 1s?

Comment: How did you write this *binary* file in the first place? You should use the `write_fileContent` method

Comment: You're wrong, the output file does contain the binary data. But your binary data just so happens to be text data. You're writing exactly what you're reading, hence you get exactly the same file.

Comment: If the input is a text file, why are you passing `ios_base::binary` when you open it?

Comment: I'm not sure that you mean by " use the write_fileContent"? I wrote that func, and I don't think it is an industry standard "method".

Comment: @Cornstalks, I know that it is doing that. The for loop in main  is showing number like 10 digits long, which I assume to be the binary representation. Is that correct? and if so, how do I get that data to write out?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your file to look like your output to stdout, then you need to write it like you do to `cout`:

```
void write_fileContent(ofstream& ost, vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {   
        ost << endl << v[i]<< endl;
    }
}
```

[`operator<<`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) does *formatted* output, while [`write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) does *unformatted* output.

Comment: That did it!! But now the file contains:

Comment: 168637746

856296757

906628400

808585741

909314573
Can I create another program that will convert from this back into int form and then output ints to a new file?

Comment: @user2904033, this is starting to feel like an XY problem, what problem are you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @shuttle87 Create a program that reads in ints, and writes out binary representation. Create a 2nd program that reverses the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
void write_fileContent(ofstream& ost, vector<int>& v)
{
    for(int i  =0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {   
        ost.write( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &v[i] ), sizeof(int) );
    }
}
```

This should work.